# French equivalent of the English expression “24/7”

Tags: expressions, indications-de-temps

After staying at a hotel in Switzerland for a month, I wanted to say a few words of thanks to the butler who was always extremely helpful to us ***around the clock***, ***24/7***.

I phrased the idea rather exaggeratedly as:

> Vous allez bien plus loin que ce que l’on attend d’un maître d'hôtel. Vous êtes disponible et accueillant ***24 heures sur 24*** ! Merci de nous avoir sortis du pétrin de temps en temps. (rires)

How does this phrasing measure up? It was the only expression that came to mind on the spot, perhaps due to the influence of a similar construction such as:

> Vous n’avez qu’***une chance sur deux*** de ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

L'expression 24 h/24 (écrit aussi « 24 h sur 24 » ou « 24 heures sur 24 » et toujours prononcé 24 heures sur vingt-quatre) est très courante. On rencontre très souvent aussi 24 h/24, 7 j/7 (7 jours sur 7).

> Votre banque 24 heures sur 24, 7 jours sur 7. [[source](https://www.cic.fr/fr/banques/particuliers/filbanque.html)]
>   Joignable 24 heures sur 24, 7 jours sur 7, [[source](http://www.24-7services.eu/)]
>
> Une centaine de supermarchés (soit un quart du parc) et une vingtaine d’hypermarchés y sont ouverts 24 h/24 et 7 jours sur 7. [[source](http://www.lsa-conso.fr/l-ouverture-des-magasins-24h-24-en-vaut-elle-le-cout,244974)]

À noter dans le dernier exemple le manque d'homogénéité dans la notation, on se serait attendu à 7 j/7.

> Bons plans OUVERTS 7J/7 24H/24 Paris [[source](http://www.paris-friendly.fr/vie-pratique-paris/ouvert-7sur7-24sur24)]

À noter dans ce dernier exemple  deux erreurs typographiques: le j et le h doivent être en **minuscules** et séparés du nombre par une **espace insécable**.

Utilisées séparément chacune des deux expressions n'est pas équivalentes.
Si 24 h/24 veut en général sous-entendre aussi 7 j/7, l'emploi de 7 j/7 seul ne sous-entend pas que ce soit 24 h/24.

Sous l'influence de l'anglais on commence à rencontrer en France 24/7, dans des titres accrocheurs, très rarement dans des textes. [Wikipedia la mentionne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/24/7) cependant comme possible, disant que « 24h/24, 7j/7 » est préféré.

Et pour les usages québécois voir la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5249).

Comment: à l'oral exclusivement on rencontre parfois **24 fois 7** pour résumer 24 h/24, 7 j/7.

Comment: Seconding this — when I visited Paris, coming from Canada, I found it hilarious to see all these 24/24 7/7 signs. (Sometimes with the h and j, sometimes without.) I guess technically 24/7 is nothing but an improper fraction!

Answer (score -3):

You're very close, it's just *24 sur 24*.

Comment: Why -1? Try googling "24 sur 24" - there are plenty of results.

Comment: The -1 is very likely for advising an almost unused expression while *24 h[eures] sur 24* is [far more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=24+sur+24%2C24+h+sur+24%2C+24+heures+sur+24&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C24%20sur%2024%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C24%20h%20sur%2024%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C24%20heures%20sur%2024%3B%2Cc0)